# Prove the convergence of the sequence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}\over a^n +b^n} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $ 0 < a < b $ then find $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}\over a^n +b^n} $$ 
Please help me find the proof for the convergence and also find the point to which it converges.

Comment: Step 1: divide top and bottom by $b^n$.

Comment: This is the approach that my professor suggested....thank u anyways..@DavidMitra

Comment: @AbhishekBhat, please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick next to the answer to indicate whether your question has been answered. It is not essential but it is considered good etiquette here. :)

Comment: See also: [If $0<a<b,$ determine the limit of $\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/840470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}=\lim \frac{(\frac{a^n}{b^n})\cdot a +b}{\frac{a^n}{b^n}+1}<b$(using $0<a<b$). So the sequence is bounded above by $b$.

Now note $\displaystyle x_n= \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$ is increasing.Use the fact that $a^nb^n(a^2+b^2)> 2ab(a^nb^n)$ and conclude that $(x_n)$ converges to $b$.

Comment: I think it'd be seriously simpler to note, after the first step, that $\;\left(\frac ab\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$ since $\;\left|\frac ab\right|<1\;$,  and finish the argument at once applying arithmetic of limits.

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah yes! wonderful indeed!