# If $0<a<b,$ determine the limit of $\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $0<a<b,$ determine $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}\right)$$
In this I am having trouble dealing with $a$ and $b$. Help me.

Answer (score 4):

Hint :

$$0<a<b\Rightarrow 0<\frac{a}{b}<1\Rightarrow (\frac{a}{b})^n\rightarrow 0$$

Answer (score 3):

big hint: divide the numerator and the denominator through $b^{n+1}$. That is if $n \to \infty$.