# Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of

Tags: limits

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of *$x^2-4x+2=0$* and let $t_n$=$\frac{\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha^n+\beta^n}$ for all $n\geqslant1$. Evaluate $\lim: \lim_{n\to \infty}t_n$.

I found roots: $2+\sqrt2$ and $2-\sqrt2$ but now I don’t know what to do

Comment: How would you approach an exercise like
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n+1}+4^{n+1}}{3^n+4^n}?$$ Can you locate the "boss terms" of the numerator and the denominator? How to take advantage?

Comment: See also: [If $0<a<b,$ determine the limit of $\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/840470) and other posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/840470).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $\alpha=2-\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta=2+\sqrt{2}.$

Since $\alpha=2-\sqrt{2}$ is less than $1$, $\alpha^n$ and $\alpha^{n+1}$ will go to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\alpha^{n+1}+\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha^n+\beta^n}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\beta^{n+1}}{\beta^n}=\beta.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One of the roots is between $0$ and $1$, while the other root is greater than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The roots are $\alpha=2-\sqrt{2}$ and $\beta=2+\sqrt{2}$. Therefore $\alpha^n\to 0$ and $\beta^n\to \infty$. Now write

$$t_n=\beta\cdot{\left({\alpha\over\beta}\right)^{n+1}+1\over\left({\alpha\over\beta}\right)^n+1}$$

And we get that $t_n\to\beta$

Comment: The point is $|{\alpha\over\beta}|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n = \alpha^n+\beta^n$. Then $x_{n+2} = 4x_{n+1} - 2x_n$ and so
$$
t_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n+2}}{x_{n+1}} = \frac{4x_{n+1} - 2x_n}{x_{n+1}} = 4 - \frac{2}{t_n}
$$
If $t_n \to L$, then $L^2 = 4L-2$ and $L=2\pm\sqrt{2}$.

By induction, $t_n \ge 2$. Therefore, $L \ge 2$ and so $L=2+\sqrt{2}$.