# How to find the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$ for $0<a<b$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the limit here ?

if $0<a<b$

**find :-**

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$

Comment: Are you sure of the denominator ? $n^n+b^n$ or $a^n+b^n$ ?

Comment: @Bswan, Can you please verify $$n^n$$ or $$a^n$$?

Comment: i edit it check it now :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove the convergence of the sequence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}\over a^n +b^n} $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714176/prove-the-convergence-of-the-sequence-lim-n-rightarrow-infty-an1-b)

Comment: See also: [If $0<a<b,$ determine the limit of $\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/840470)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methink the ratio is $$\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{a^n+b^n}=\frac{a(a/b)^n+b}{(a/b)^n+1}$$

Now $0<a/b<1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}(a/b)^n=0$

Comment: The post gives a denominator $n^n+b^n$. Ahah !! Cheers

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, $n^n$ won't make the problem too interesting :)

Comment: thank you so much ,very helpfull

Comment: I totally agree (once more) with you but this was a very funny situation. :)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici :) it was a typo :P now it fixed so it make sense that the limit is a+b

Comment: Sure it was ! And a good one since you got answers before you fixed the post. Thanks and cheers :)